# SQL: having trouble with listing min, max, average, count

Tags: mysql, sql, select, max, min

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5Pzz.png I am currently trying to list the min, max, avg, and count for each assignmentID. the code i used to create whats shown in the picture is as follows:

```
SELECT assignment.assignmentID, assignment.assignmentName, grade.grade

FROM grade 

JOIN assignment ON grade.assignmentID = assignment.assignmentID
```

When I add in the min,max,avg,count to the SELECT function it only returns the results for assignmentID 1. how can i get it to do it for all assignments

Comment: Please provide the table's DDL, some sample data as DML, expected results and the actual query you have right now (with `min()`, `max()`, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're not grouping by the assignment record. Use [`group by`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html) to perform the aggregation on a per-assignment basis:

```
select assignment.assignmentID, assignment.assignmentName,
    count(*) as gradeCount, avg(grade.grade) as avgGrade,
    min(grade.grade) as minGrade, max(grade.grade) as maxGrade
from assignment, grade
where assignment.assignmentID = grade.assignmentID
group by assignment.assignmentID, assignment.assignmentName
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want:

```
SELECT a.assignmentID, a.assignmentName,
       COUNT(*) as numgrades, MIN(g.grade), MAX(g.grade), AVG(g.grade)
FROM assignment a JOIN
     grade g
     ON g.assignmentID = a.assignmentID
GROUP BY a.assignmentID, a.assignmentName;
```

Your query was missing the `GROUP BY` and the aggregation functions.  This assumes that `grade` is numeric, so the `AVG()` makes sense.

Notice that I also introduced table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.